# trying to pass a structure with two elements to a function (without using pointers) to get a new output for the two elements

Tags: c, function

SO im writing a piece of code to translate a point of x and y, which are elements of a structure, in the x direction, y direction and rotating around the origin based on user inputs for x, y and an angle theta respectively. How do i pass the structure through the function for the rotation (without using pointers as we haven't covered that yet), thanks. code is below, thanks.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct
{
float x;
float y;
}coordinate;

float xNew(float x, float x2);
float yNew(float y, float y2);
coordinate Rotate( coordinate pointA, float angle);


void main()

{

coordinate pointA;
float x,y,x2,y2, theta;
 coordinate newpoints;

printf("Enter coordinates>");
scanf("%f%f", &pointA.x, &pointA.y);

printf("Enter x offset>");
scanf("%f", &x2);
x = xNew(pointA.x, x2);

printf("Enter y offset>");
scanf("%f", &y2);
y = yNew(pointA.y, y2);

printf("Enter rotation value in degrees");
scanf("%f", &theta);
newpoints = Rotate(pointA, theta);

printf("offsets were %f%f\n",x2,y2 );
printf("new coords are%f%f\n", x,y);
pointA.x = x;
pointA.y = y;
printf("struc coords are%f%f", pointA.x, pointA.y);
return;
}

float xNew(float x, float x2)
{
float xpos;

xpos = x+x2;
return(xpos);
}

float yNew(float y, float y2)
{
float ypos;

ypos = y + y2;
return(ypos);

coordinate Rotate( pointA, float angle)
{

  coordinate pointA;
  float theta;

pointA.x = cos(theta)*pointA.x - sin(theta)*pointA.y;
pointA.y = sin(theta)*pointA.x + cos(theta)*pointA.y;

return(pointA);

}
}
```

EDIT: Posted the updated code, only getting one error

error: expected ‘)’ before ‘float’
 coordinate Rotate( pointA, float angle)
i dont know whats going on

Comment: Sorry that was the old one, new code is up, i dont know how to pass my pointA struc to the function to get the new coordinates when rotated

Comment: Noted, @TomKarzes.

Comment: Are you posting all this code just to ask about the syntax error? If so, please post the entire error message verbatim.

Comment: Yes, having the code helps with finding the problem i think

Comment: Posting a minimal example helps with finding the problem. Posting your actual project obfuscates it, if anything.

Comment: Ok sorry about that, i'll keep that in mind when evaluating future posts.

Comment: Please don't user typedef for this. You gain nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, try to indent your code for better readability.
Second, this is my first answer so bear with me.

Now, the first mistake I noticed was this:

```
float yNew(float y, float y2)
{
float ypos;

ypos = y + y2;
return(ypos);

coordinate Rotate( pointA, float angle)
{

  coordinate pointA;
  float theta;

pointA.x = cos(theta)*pointA.x - sin(theta)*pointA.y;
pointA.y = sin(theta)*pointA.x + cos(theta)*pointA.y;

return(pointA);

}
}
```

1. The `Rotate` function seems to be nested, when you want it to be 'outside'.
2. `pointA` is already used as a parameter(without declaring the type), and then you are redeclaring it within the function.

3.`theta` is being declared and used uninitialized. In fact, it is a redundant variable.

4. `pointA` is declared without type. `coordinate`

The updated code is:

```
float yNew(float y, float y2)
{
float ypos;

ypos = y + y2;
return(ypos);
}

coordinate Rotate(coordinate pointA, float angle)
{

  coordinate pointB;

pointB.x = cos(angle)*pointA.x - sin(angle)*pointA.y;
pointB.y = sin(angle)*pointA.x + cos(angle)*pointA.y;

return(pointB);

}
```

You have declared `newpoints` but never used it. So the output values are of the original structure(inputted ones). Try this:

```
printf("Enter rotation value in degrees");
scanf("%f", &theta);
newpoints = Rotate(pointA, theta);

printf("offsets were %f%f\n",x2,y2 );
printf("new coords are%f%f\n", x,y);

printf("struc coords are%f   %f", newpoints.x, newpoints.y);
```

I didn't check the transformation formula, though.

Comment: I just noticed the besting before you posted, thanks for the advice, i updated the code (i see where i went wrong), its still giving the the same syntax error :/

Comment: at what line are you getting the error?  Because in my IDE(Eclipse), it shows no errors of such kind.

Comment: it's line 61:26

Comment: I closes the yNew function with {}, however im still getting the error

Comment: It works now! :) thank you! so coordinate pointA can be read as a parameter like "input a structure like coordinate"?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so.

On an unrelated note, it looks like you are new to C. So, before you write any program, try to have a flowchart/mindmap of what you are gonna do. It will help.


Bonus tip: use ```int main()``` instead of ```void main()```